# How to call a function in a different process using Connections

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to realize some sort oft client-server-connection using Python and are rather new to multiprocessing. Basically, I have a class 'Manager' that inherits from multiprocessing.Process and manages the connection from a client to different data sources. This process has some functions like 'get_value(key)' that should return the value of the key-data source. Now, as I want this to run asynchronized, I cannot simply call this function from my client process.

My idea so far would be that I connect the Client- and Manager-Processes using a Pipe and then send a message from the Client to the Manager to execute this function. I would realize this by sending a list through the pipe where the first element is the name of the function the remaining elements are the arguments of the actual function, e.g. ['get_value', 'datasource1']. The process then would receive this and send the return value through the pipe to the client. This would look something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

class Manager(Process):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super(Process, self).__init__()
        self.connection = connection

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.connection.poll():
                msg = self.connection.recv()
                self.call_function(msg[0], msg[:])

    def call_function(self, name, *args):
        print('Function Called with %s' % name)
        return_val = getattr(self, name)(*args)
        self.connection.send(return_val)

    def get_value(self, key):
        return 1.0
```

While I guess that this would work, I am not very happy with this solution. Especially the call-function-by-string-method seems very error-prone. Is there a more elegant way of requesting to execute a function in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach, all in all, is a good one (there are other ways to do the same thing, of course, but there is nothing wrong with your general approach).

That said, I would change the design slightly to add a "routing" component: think of some logic that somehow limits what "commands" can be sent by clients, and hooks between commands and "handlers" - that is functions that handle them. Basically think Web Framework routing (if you are familiar with the concept).

This is a good idea both in terms of flexibility of the design, in terms of error detection and in terms of security (you don't want clients to call `['__del__']` for example on your `Manager`.

At it's very basic form, a `router` can be a dictionary mapping commands to class methods:

```
class Manager(Process):
    def __init__(self, connection):
      super(Process, self).__init__()
      self.connection = connection

      self.routes = {'do_action': self._do_action,
                     'do_other_action': some_callable,
                     'ping': lambda args: args}  # <- as long as it's callable and has the right signature...

  def call_function(self, name, *args):
      try:
          handler = self.routes[name]
      except KeyError:
          return self._error_reply('{} is not a valid command'.format(name))

      try:
          return_val = handler(*args)  # handler functions will need to throw something if arguments are wrong...
      except ValueError as e:
          return self._error_reply('Invalid command arguments: {}'.format(str(e)))
      except Exception as e:
          # This is your catch-all "internal server error" handler
          return self._error_reply(str(e))

      self.connection.send(return_val)
```

This is of course just an example of an approach. You will need to implement `_error_reply()` in whatever way works for you.

You can expand on it by creating a `Router` class and passing it as a dependency to Manager, making it even more flexible. You might also want to think about making your Manager a separate thing and not a subclass of `Process` (because you might want to run it regardless of whether it is in a subprocess - for example in testing).

BTW, there are frameworks for implementing such things with various degrees of complexity and flexibility (Thrift, ZeroMQ, ...), but if you want to do something simple and *learn*, doing it yourself is in my opinion a great choice.